# How to tell compactness in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Compactness is defined fundamentally using the Heine-Borel theorem. In terms of $\mathbb{R}$, we have a more straightforward theorem that tells compactness: a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. How to extend this theorem to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? The difficulty is, how to define "boundedness" in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I am not aware of a "less than" symbol for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that helps with the definition. Also, even with a proper definition, I am not sure if the theorem in $\mathbb{R}$ can be well extended to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Boundness in TVS or metric space → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Boundedness_in_topological_vector_spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compactness is not defined using the Heine-Borel theorem; the usual definition using open covers makes sense in any topological space.

A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if and only if there is an $R > 0$ so that $A \subset B(0, R) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| < R\}$, where $|x|$ is the norm of $x$.

Comment: I see. So with this definition of "boundedness", compactness can be conveniently defined as "closed and bounded", correct?

Comment: According to the Heine-Borel theorem, a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, yes (this is the statement of the Heine--Borel theorem). In more general spaces, you would need other conditions.